# How to make a JButtons appear

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jbutton

I want to make a JButton that lies on the NorthPane of the frame, but when I run the program there's no button. Why does it do that?
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA.
BTW I'm posting this question again, cause the first time  I didn't get the desired answer.

Here's my code.

```java
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;

class Fantasyrpglifesim implements JButton {
    Fantasyrpglifesim() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MouseInputAdapter();
        //Frame//
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1500, 1500);
        frame.getContentPane();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(northPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH );
        //frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());//

        //Buttons//
        frame.add(BUTTON);
        BUTTON.setText("Age up");
        northPanel.add(BUTTON);
        northPanel.add(BUTTON1);
        BUTTON1.setText("Test");
        northPanel.add(BUTTON2);
        BUTTON2.setText("Test1");
        northPanel.add(BUTTON2);
        BUTTON2.setText("Test2");
        northPanel.add(BUTTON3);
        BUTTON3.setText("Test3");
        northPanel.add(BUTTON4);
        BUTTON4.setText("Test4");
        northPanel.add(BUTTON5);
        BUTTON5.setText("Test5");
        northPanel.add(BUTTON6);
        BUTTON6.setText("Test6");
        northPanel.add(BUTTON7);
        BUTTON7.setText("Test7");
        northPanel.add(BUTTON8);
        BUTTON8.setText("Test8");
        northPanel.add(BUTTON9);
        BUTTON9.setText("Test9");
        northPanel.add(BUTTON10);
        BUTTON10.setText("Test10");
        northPanel.add(BUTTON11);
       BUTTON11.setText("Test11");
        northPanel.add(BUTTON12);
        BUTTON12.setText("Test12");
        northPanel.add(BUTTON13);
        BUTTON13.setText("Test13");
        northPanel.setVisible(true);

        //panels//
        //mainPanel.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);//
    }


    private static void MouseInputAdapter() {
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding a screenshot of the output

Comment: I don't see your definition for BUTTON

Comment: also this isn't javascript

Comment: sorry i thought java and javascript were the same thing

Answer (score 0):

to add a JButton you have to create a JButton object and add that to the JPanel.
And you need to define it for EVERY button that you want to have.
anywhere. I'm surprised your compiler isn't flagging that

Anyway what you want should look sth like this

```
        JButton testButton = new JButton("test");
        northPanel.add(testButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I want you to check your compiler and IntelliJ cause they're not working if you can run the code you posted.

You cannot `implement` a `JButton` unless you have made an interface yourself.
Cause the `JButton` is not an interface.

1. No need to set a BorderLayout for your `JPanel`. FlowLayout will do the job.
2. Use a `for` loop to avoid duplicate code.
3. Learn how to use [Swing components.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Fantasyrpglifesim {
    private  static int count = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        JButton age = new JButton("Age up");
        mainPanel.add(age);

        for (int x=0; x<14;x++){
            JButton button = new JButton();
            button.setText("Test"+ count++);
            mainPanel.add(button);
        }

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH,mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1500, 1500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Is this your desired output?

Comment: From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.lang.String,java.awt.Component)) of method `add(String, java.awt.Component)` in class `java.awt.Container`: _This method is obsolete as of 1.1. Please use the method `add(Component, Object)` instead._ You also no longer need to call method `getcontentPane`. Hence you should probably write: `frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);`